# Is it possible to extend User Settings in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops

I found a few hints on extension points or 'contributions' for Azure DevOps page:

1. https://github.com/microsoft/vsts-extension-samples/blob/master/contributions-guide/vss-extension.json
2. https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-samples.samples-contributions-guide

Is there any other place I could check out for extension points? Microsoft deleted the documentation on it some time ago. This https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/devops/docs/extend/reference/targets/overview?view=azure-devops&viewFallbackFrom=vsts outputs 404.

I would like to extend "User Settings" page. Is it possible? What's the contribution target for that?
Or is there any alternative way to do it? E.g. a hub with which would load data for a specific user?

Comment: There's an archived version of the docs site available: https://web.archive.org/web/20201005200511/https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/devops/docs/extend/reference/targets/overview?view=azure-devops

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, the documentation of extension targets has not been deleted.

Here is the link about the extension targets: [Azure DevOps extensibility points](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/devops/extend/reference/targets/overview).

As shown in [Github Link](https://github.com/microsoft/vsts-extension-samples/blob/master/contributions-guide/vss-extension.json) in your question, it also contains long list supported extension targets

But I am afraid there is no extension targets to support extending User Settings page for users and there is no workaround could meet your requirements.

In addition, this is a suggestion ticket with the same requirement: [Add extension point - User admin hub](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/962147/add-extension-point-user-admin-hub.html)  in our UserVoice Site.  You could vote it and add your requirement in the comment.